# JQuery, using Sortable in a calendar

Tags: jquery, calendar, draggable, jquery-ui-sortable

I am building an event calendar and using the sortable function in jQuery. My goal is to allow users to drag events to any day on the calendar.

A day can have multiple events, and my day DIV looks like this.

```
<div>
  <ul id="day1" class="day">
    <li class="eventDetail" id="1_1">Event 1</li>
    <li class="eventDetail" id="1_2">Event 2</li>
    <li class="eventDetail" id="1_3">Event 3</li>
  </ul>
</div>
```

Here's my sortable function

```
$(".eventDetail").sortable({
    connectWith: ".eventDetail",
    update: (function(event, ui){
        alert($(this).text());
    })
}).disableSelection();
```

I am using the update parameter to alert the current text value. However, I am receiving ALL text values for a given group of LI's. E.G, For the one above my alert looks like "EVENT 1, EVENT 2, EVENT 3" - Why?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this instead:

```
...
update: (function(event, ui){
    alert($(ui.item).text());
    alert($(ui.placeholder).text());
}
...
```

Comment: BTW, My alert is happening twice, can you explain why?

Comment: Actually, it's only appearing twice if I drag it to a new day. I figure the first alert is for the element I moved, and the second alert is for the element that was bumped because of the first element.

Comment: Well the state of the two sortables changes in this case that's why `update` event fires twice.

Comment: Here is an example how you can distinguish those cases. http://jsfiddle.net/WY6ru/1/

Comment: Thanks dfsq. I'm having a bit of an issue with the <li>'s being physically moved to the new day. In my code above, I have 3 events. If I was to move event 3 from day 1 to day 2, I can not longer move an event from another day back to position 3 in day 1, as there is no LI there.

Any thoughts on how to approach this? Do I need to change my connectWith value?

Comment: I thinks you should initialize sortables on `UL` elements like in my example fiddle. Not on `LI`'s like you do.

Comment: Hi dfsq,

Hmm that didn't seem to make a difference, I am still losing the ability to move events back to the previous day.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the ui item in the callback to get info on just the dragged item. (You also need to call .sortable on the `<ul>` tag).

See this demo: http://jsfiddle.net/WY6ru/

Comment: Why do I need to call sortable on the ul as well?